# Given a set $A$ of sets find a minimal set $B$ of pair-wise disjoint sets such that each set in $A$ can be expressed as a union of sets in $B$

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, sets

I recently thought of the following problem:

Given a set $A$ of sets find a minimal set $B$ of pair-wise disjoint sets such that each set in $A$ can be expressed as a union of sets in $B$.

For example, if $A = \{ \{ 1, 2 \}, \{ 1, 2, 3 \}, \{3, 4\}, \{4\} \}$ then $B = \{ \{ 1, 2 \}, \{ 3 \}, \{ 4 \} \}$.

I designed the following algorithm:

1. Let $B = \emptyset$ initially.
2. Let $S$ be the set of set(s) of lowest of cardinality in $A$.
3. Let $I$ be the intersection of the sets in $S$.
4. If $I = \emptyset$: add the sets in $S$ to $B$, remove the elements in the sets in $S$ from the sets in $A$, and remove $\emptyset$ from $A$.

   If $I \neq \emptyset$: add $I$ to $B$, remove the elements in $I$ from the sets in $A$, and remove $\emptyset$ from $A$.
5. Repeat from step 2 until $A = \emptyset$.

My questions are:

- Does this problem have a name?
- Is this algorithm correct?
- What is the complexity of this algorithm?
- Is this algorithm optimal, and if not, what would be a better algorithm?

Comment: Call two elements in the base set *equivalent* if they belong to the same sets from $A$. Now your sets $B$ are the equivalence classes. This of course is not an algorithm, but it might help solving the problem.

Comment: @HendrikJan When you say "two elements in the base set" is "elements" referring to sets in the base set $A$ or elements in the sets in $A$?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to explain. Indeed, the elements in the sets in $A$. So here the base set would be $\{1,2,3,4\}$.

Comment: You start with smallest sets. Start however with the full set and split. Begin with $\{1,2,3,4\}$. First set in $A$ shows we get $\{1,2\},\{3,4\}$. Second set needs another split $\{1,2\},\{3\},\{4\}$

Comment: @HendrikJan I'm not sure I fully understand how you decide where to split, but if you could post an answer explaining further that would be great.

Comment: My proposed solution is similar to the answer by xskxzr, although he uses another terminology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially you are finding all non-empty components of the Venn diagram of the sets in $A$. So here is an algorithm:

```
B = empty set
for each set S in A:
    for each set T in B:
        remove T from B
        compute (S \cap T), (T \ S) and (S \ T) 
        if (S \cap T) is not empty, add (S \cap T) into B
        if (T \ S) is not empty, add (T \ S) into B
        S = S \ T
    if S is not empty, add S into B
return B
```

This algorithm runs in $O(nm)$ time where $n$ is the number of all elements involved, and $m$ is the number of sets in $A$.

---

For your example, initially $B$ is empty.

After dealing with $\{1,2\}$, $B=\{\{1,2\}\}$.

After dealing with $\{1,2,3\}$, $B=\{\{1,2\},\{3\}\}$.

After dealing with $\{3,4\}$, $B=\{\{1,2\},\{3\},\{4\}\}$.

After dealing with $\{4\}$, $B=\{\{1,2\},\{3\},\{4\}\}$.

Comment: Would you be able to clarify what you mean by "components" in the context of Venn diagrams? I am not familiar with what qualifies as a "component" in a Venn diagram. Additionally, do you have any intuition you could share with me to help me understand why the algorithm works?

Comment: For $n$ sets $A_1,\ldots,A_n$, each component can be expressed as $X_1\cap \cdots\cap X_n$ where $X_i$ is either $A_i$ or $\bar{A}_i$. There are $2^n-1$ components ($\bar{A}_1\cap \cdots\cap \bar{A}_n$ is always empty since the universe is $A_1\cup \cdots\cup A_n$).

Answer (score 1):

This problem sounds very interesting. I am not aware of any name for this problem, however.

Your algorithm is not correct.

Here is a counterexample. $A = \{ \{ 1, 2 \}, \{ 1, 3 \}, \{1, 4\}, \{2,3\}, \{2,4\}\}$. The minimal set of pairwise disjoint sets such that each set in A can be expressed as a union of sets in it is $B = \{ \{1\}, \{2 \}, \{ 3 \}, \{ 4 \} \}$, which has 4 elements. However, in the step 4 of your algorithm, all 5 sets in $A$ will be added.

In fact, as you pointed out, the step 4 may add non-disjoint sets, thus invalidating the algorithm. The smallest counterexample is $A = \{\{1, 2 \}, \{2, 3 \}, \{1,3\}\}$. The step 4 of the algorithm will add all 3 sets in $A$, which contains no disjoint pairs.

Comment: Well looks like it's back to the drawing board... An even simpler counterexample would be $A = \{ \{ 1, 2 \}, \{ 2, 3 \}, \{ 3, 4 \} \}$.